# Is it safe to use HTML5 Web SQL Database API?

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

After reading http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ and more specifically:

> This document was on the W3C Recommendation track but specification
>   work has stopped. The specification reached an impasse: all interested
>   implementors have used the same SQL backend (Sqlite), but we need
>   multiple independent implementations to proceed along a
>   standardisation path.

I am wondering if it is "safe" (i.e. ongoing support) to use the HTML5 Database API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is strongly inadvisable. It has stopped and is being replaced with the [`IndexedDB` API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/). Eventually, Web SQL Database will be removed from browsers which currently support it.

You might like to read current browser support figures for [Web SQL Database](http://caniuse.com/sql-storage) and [IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb). Web SQL Database has more browsers which currently support it, but Firefox doesn't support it and outweighs Safari, Opera and assorted mobile browsers, and so it's only at about 28% while IndexedDB is near 36% global support. Also, I believe it is generally believed that Microsoft will support IndexedDB in IE10, while the Web SQL Database API will not be going any further.

**Update, 2013-02-04:** IE10 *does* support IndexedDB; Web SQL and IndexedDB are both just under 50% support. IndexedDB spec compliance is also very good which has led to IE10, Firefox and Chrome all now supporting it unprefixed.

Answer (score 2):

No. In bigger, bolder letters is the text,

> **Beware. This specification is no longer in active maintenance and the
>   Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further.**